# AngularJS repeater which has several inline filtering for a complex model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm totally new to AngularJS, so would like some advice on how to do this.

Instead of creating several chunky 'blocks' of filter code, is it possible to neatly have several show/hide filters within a repeater? This would greatly ease the readability at first glance and is less code comparing to the Custom Filters/Tutorial 9 in the AngularJS site.

Something like:

```
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:(showIf phone.brand == 'Nexus') | orderBy:orderProp">
       {{phone.name}}
       <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="price in phone.prices | filter:(showIf price < 100)">${{price}}</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
```

**Edited:**

Would this work and how do I hide the parent `UL` if there are no `LI`s?

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:{brand: 'Nexus'} | orderBy:orderProp">
   {{phone.name}}
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="price in phone.prices | filter:{price: < 100}">${{price}}</li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: yikes.. color-coding gone astray with my imaginary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Filter dev guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) in the Angular docs. It's entirely possible.

Your first example, `showIf phone.brand == 'Nexus'` is best done with the built-in Filter somewhat confusingly named `filter`.

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:{brand: 'Nexus'}">{{ phone }}</li>
```

Your second example is somewhat more complicated because of the `<` operator, but can be solved by using the same `filter`-filter with a custom comparator function, or by creating your own custom filter.

Example comparator function:

```
$scope.lessThan = function(expected, actual) {
    return actual < expected;
}
```

Used like:

```
<li ng-repeat="price in phone.prices | filter:{price: 100}:lessThan">{{price}}</li>
```

Comment: Would like to apply the filter inline and on the repeater rather than the repeater item as shown in one of the guide examples. Would you be able give a code example for other operators other than equal in the ng-repeat DOM, or even multiple (slightly more complex) filters ?

Comment: Added example with comparator function.

Comment: Thanks Mikke, I'll go with what you have, but leave this question open for a while in case there are different approaches.